# How do I create this sequence?

Tags: r, sequence

```
10.000 5.000 2.500 1.250 0.625
```

How do I create the above sequence (WITHOUT using c())? I am thinking seq() and rep() functions might help.
TIA

Comment: Try `10 / 2^(0:4)`.

Comment: @27ϕ9 Could you explain how did that work? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since there is mathematical relationship you can use some math:

```
c(0.625,1.250,2.500,5.000,10.000)
```

[1]  0.625  1.250  2.500  5.000 10.000

```
0.625*c(1,2,4,8,16)
```

[1]  0.625  1.250  2.500  5.000 10.000

```
0.625*2^(0:4)
```

[1]  0.625  1.250  2.500  5.000 10.000

Answer (score 1):

As you said, seq() function works.

```
    10 * .5^seq(0,4, by = 1)
```

result is

```
    [1] 10.000  5.000  2.500  1.250  0.625
```

Comment: Thanks! But could you explain how did that work? I am struggling to understand the logic behind this.

Comment: Above sequence is geometric sequence. seq(0,4 , by = 1) means arithmetic sequence from 0 to 4 by 1.
So, my code means 10 * (.5^0, .5^1, ..., .5^4)

Comment: yea I knew that I was asking how did you know it was 0.5^...?

Comment: It goes half in above sequence